# Undefined reference in simple Qt program

Tags: c++, qt, undefined

I'm a beginner making a program in Qt creator. I made a button that should open Google Chrome using `QtProcess::execute()`, but I'm getting following errors:

```
F:\Users\Amol-2\Desktop\Imp Docs\C++ apps\build-QtMainLProject-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp:71: error: undefined reference to `MainWindow::buttonClickHandler()'`
:-1: error:  ld returned 1 exit status
```

**`mainwindow.cpp`:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_openChrome_clicked()
{
    QString exeloc = "F:\\Users\\Amol-2\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
    QProcess::execute(exeloc);
}
```

**`mainwindow.h`:**

```
    namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void buttonClickHandler();


public slots:
    void on_openChrome_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any funtion buttonClickHandler declared in the MainWindow class, which you forgot to define?

Comment: yes, I have declared buttonClickHandler in mainwindow.h file and defined it in mainwindow.cpp.

Comment: Your code does not show your buttonClickHandler in the mainwindow.cpp which you have supplied

Comment: I'm totally confused now if I have not defined it in my code so tell me how and where to define it

Comment: Add `void MainWindow::buttonClickHandler() { ... }` to your .cpp file.

Comment: Suggestion: Check you include Folder in your Project for the file which is causing the error. I have found copies of deleted files there which causes the ambiguous reference error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have this in your `.h` file:

```
public slots:
    void buttonClickHandler();
```

It's a method *declaration*, and it's a Qt slot, so Qt *moc* will generate code which references it (to call it for connected signals etc). And then linker tries to link that code to create your application binary. But you don't have the method *defintion* (actual code) anywhere, it seems.

3 possible fixes:

### 1.

Remove that slot *declaration* from the `.h` file, since you don't seem to be using it.

### 2.

Add *defionition* by changing above snippet to this in the `.h` file:

```
public slots:
    void buttonClickHandler() { /* add code if you want some */ }
```

This turns the *declaration* into a *definition* (of inline member function).

### 3.

Alternatively, add method *definition* to the `.cpp` file, like you have for your other methods:

```
void MainWindow::buttonClickHandler() {
    // your code here
}
```